# How do I overcome my visibility issue with scanned PDF files?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, colors, adobe-acrobat, contrast

I'm a visually impaired person. I need to create mathematical PDF documents using latex.

I'm using Windows XP SP3 with High Contrast Black (Large) display scheme because my eyesight isn't comfortable viewing the screen with light background.

In the Adobe Acrobat Reader, I've checked the "Replace Document Colors" check box and then the "Use Windows Color Scheme" radio button on the "Accessibility" of the "Preferences..." dialog box, which is accessible from the Edit menu.

However, while these settings work just fine for me in certain PDF documents, I find that there are certain other kind of PDF documents --- perhaps those scanned documents that have been saved as .pdf files --- in which my settings changes have no effect, and in those problematic documents, dark text appears against a light background, making reading those documents too stressful on my eyes!

What is the way out for me?

Will this issue go away if I migrate to Windows 7 or later?

I would prefer this issue to get resolved without having to use any screen magnification software, such as MAGic or Zoom Text Xtra.

I'm currently using Adobe Reader 11.0.10.

Comment: This has very little to do with Windows XP over Windows 7.  It has to do with Adobe Reader and the disability features it has or does not have.

Comment: As you seem to suspect, if they've scanned in a page of black text on a white piece of paper, and didn't use OCR, then you're looking at a *picture* of black text on a white page, so no UI color settings will apply.  Can you provide a link to one of the PDFs that's giving you problems? We may be able to come up with a workable solution if we have something to test with. :)

Answer (score 3):

Scanned documents are saved as bitmaps, not text. This means that Adobe can't do much about the image itself. Perhaps there's an "invert colors" option, like there is in Foxit reader. Alternatively, you may want to consider giving Foxit Reader a try.

Alternatives are programs that can convert and OCR the images to text, and then allow you to change the colors as you're used to.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Can you recomend some particularly good program that, as you put it, can convert and OCR the images to text, and then allow me to change the colors as I'm used to?

Comment: Program recommendations are off-topic here on SuperUser, so instead I'll tell you what to search for in google. Search for `Convert PDF Word` Note, this will require you to buy a program.

Comment: You can change pdf colors using this tool: https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/. It works with scanned/raster or vector PDF documents.